# Histogram Program

Tags: python, histogram

I am working on a Lab program that asks to create a program that asks to print inputted scores (separated by commas) and adds an asterisk for every time the score is listed. The program I have listed is short and seems like it should work, but I am just having trouble in the sense if I am making this question too simple than what it really is. Can anyone help with a few ideas why this is not working and an idea of what to do here?

```
test_scores = input("Enter test scores: ").split(",")

for num in range(0,101):
    count = test_scores.count(num)
    if count > 0:
      print(num)
```

Completed Program:

```
test_scores = input("Enter test scores: ").split(",")

a_set = sorted(set(test_scores))
test_scores.sort()

for score in a_set:
    x = test_scores.count(score)
    print(score,('*'*x))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "adds an asterisk..." also if you're just trying to print out the elements in the list why not just iterate the list and print out the elements? If you want the *unique* elements then you can use a `set`. Not sure I understand what it is you're trying to achieve

Comment: Write a program (call it Histogram.py) that inputs a string of comma separated test scores
from the user and prints out a histogram of the scores. The histogram should have one row
on it for each distinct test score, followed by one star for each test score of that value. For
example, if the tests scores in the file were 55, 80, 80, 95, 95, 95 and 98, the output to the
screen should look like:
55*
80**
95***
98*
I believe including the actual description would be better

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an assignment and I don't want to code your lab for you I'll outline an approach you can implement. This is the simplest way (imo) given your comment you said histogram but listed score(asterisks = num appearances) ...

If you want an actual histogram put to the OS with axes where the scores are vertically aligned with the "bars" which would be asterisks of height = num occurences then that will require additional work. So, I'll outline the approach for what you listed in your comment.

1. Your first line is fine for getting the list of scores and splitting them into a list (assuming the user input is fine)
2. You're iterating over 1-100 which is all possible scores. Redundant imo, why not just sort the list and then print out the number with the number of asterisks required?

Hint: `sort` is handy here and you can iterate and print items in a list by doing (for example)

```
for element in aSortedList: 
    #do something with "element"
```

3. For each score you want a number of asterisks equal to the number of occurrences in the list displayed next to the score.

For strings recall you can do `(string) * (num)` for a string that repeats itself num times.

Hint: As you are you can get the number of occurences in the list with `count`. Then use `(string) * (num)`.

There you go.

Comment: I added an update with a code that so far has done what I needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your right, apologies haven't used Python in awhile. So, what was your updated question...?

Comment: The assignment is complete. It was just showing the finished product. I should add that.

Comment: Ah, okay was confused for a moment given the update. If the question is answered would you mind marking it as such? (Check mark)